# Which Wordpress directory would be valid?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting

My apology for such a noob question.

On my hosting server, there are two Wordpress installations - one in www/html directory and another in root.

Can you please let me know which one would refer to the actual wordpress installation?

Comment: How can we know? You could delete `index.php` (after backing it up, of course) and see if it still works ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the one that you see when you browse the site, it's www/html.